# Communication between Azure IoTHub and Azure IoTEdge?

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

I have cloned Azure IoT Edge from https://github.com/Azure/iot-edge. And build this using build.sh script resides in tools directory.
Now I run sample application "simulated device" and it communicates with the Azure IoT Hub. But now I want to send messages from IoTHub to this Simulated device app, it has Receive function which receive data from IoTHub. So I used device explorer to send messages, but every time it does not deliver to simulated device at instatnly, but when I restart simulated device program again, then that previous message has received. Could you please tell me, what I have to do for message receiving from IoT Hub to Azure IoT Edge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the simulated device is connecting to IoT Hub using HTTPS, it checks for cloud-to-device messages when it starts up, and then polls for cloud-to-device messages. The recommended polling time is to check every 25 minutes. If the simulated device uses AMQP or MQTT, cloud-to-device messages are pushed to the device. For more information see:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-protocols
- https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-c2d-guidance